# Loop cut and change color problem

Tags: modeling

In edit mode, when a cube is loop cut and divided into two faces, one face is selected and the color is changed, but only that face needs to be changed, why does the other face change color
[image: []

Comment: if you want to give another to this face, you need to give it a new material (in the Material panel, click on the "+" button on the right of the material list, then press New...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only have one material applied to the cube mesh (Material.002), this material will be applied to every face of the cube. If you want different colors in your cube you must first create different materials in the *Materials Properties* tab, by clicking the *plus +* button:

[image]

Once you have multiple materials created, you just need to assign them to the desired faces of your cube. In edit mode, select the faces, select the material and click *Assign*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer!